# Properly inverting text and background colors w/in CSS animation?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to make text invert color between its background and its own color during the course of an animation.

Right now I can get it to flip the colors the first time fine, but when it should transition back so that the colors are the default again it just makes a muddled color somewhere between the two instead. Below is what I currently have written for the animation:

```css
body {
  background: #3866af;
  color: #ffebb5;
}

.blink {
  animation: blink-animation 1s steps(2, start) infinite;
}

@keyframes blink-animation {
  from {
    background: #3866af;
    color: #ffebb5;
  }
  to {
    background: #ffebb5;
    color: #3866af;
  }
}
```

```html
This is how text would normally look 
<br>
<span class="blink">and this is what blinking text looks like right now</span>
```

What I want is for the letters to become blue and the background of those letters to become beige.

I am hoping to not have to use javascript for this task, since I believe it can be accomplished entirely with CSS.

Thanks!

EDIT:

My chosen solution comes from Farhad Bagherlo's answer below:

```css
body {
  background: #3866af;
  color: #ffebb5;
}

.blink {
  animation: blink-animation 1s steps(2, start) infinite;
}

@keyframes blink-animation {
    0% {
       background-color:#3866af;
       color: #ffebb5;
    }
    50% {
       background-color:#3866af;
       color: #ffebb5;
    }
    51% {
       background-color: #ffebb5;
       color:#3866af;
    }
    100% {
       background-color: #ffebb5;
       color:#3866af;
    }
}
```

```html
This is how text would normally look 
<br>
<span class="blink">and this is what blinking text looks like right now</span>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```css
body {
  background: #3866af;
  color: #ffebb5;
}

.blink {
  animation: blink-animation 1s steps(4, start) infinite;

}

@keyframes blink-animation {
0% {
       background-color:#3866af;
    color: #ffebb5;
  }
  50% {
      background-color:#3866af;
    color: #ffebb5;
  }
  75% {
  background-color: #ffebb5;
    color:#3866af;
  }
  100% {
    background-color: #ffebb5;
    color:#3866af;
  }
}
```

```html
This is how text would normally look 
<br>
<span class="blink">and this is what blinking text looks like right now</span>
```

Comment: Awesome, almost exactly what I'm looking for, I just swapped `75%{}` for `51%{}` to get the flat blink effect instead of a fade.